# Get all Schema.org schemas under a specific category (Place, LocalBusiness)

Tags: export, schema, schema.org

I'm wondering if there is a website or a way to get the list of all the Schema.org schemas under a specific category (ex: `Place`).

I found the [complete list on Schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/full.html) - they also provide a JSON-LD file - but there's no way to filter/order this *easily*.

My goal is to get the list of all the places in a nice array (PHP, JSON, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Most vocabularies/ontologies are defined using [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework).

The vocabulary Schema.org is no exception. The [canonical/machine-readable representation of Schema.org](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581346/1591669) is provided in HTML+RDFa:

**http://schema.org/docs/schema_org_rdfa.html**

This file always contains the current release. If you are interested in specific versions of Schema.org, [snapshots are available](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/57889/17633).

As a quick overview:

- Each Schema.org **type** is of type [`rdfs:Class`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_class).

  - **Sub-types** are specified with the [`rdfs:subClassOf`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_subclassof) property.
- Each Schema.org **property** is of type [`rdf:Property`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_property).

  - **Sub-properties** are specified with the [`rdfs:subPropertyOf`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_subpropertyof) property.
  - The **domains** of a property (i.e., on which types this property is expected) are specified with the [`schema:domainIncludes`](http://schema.org/domainIncludes) property.
  - The **ranges** of a property (i.e., which values are expected) are specified with the [`schema:rangeIncludes`](http://schema.org/rangeIncludes) property.

RDFa is a RDF serialization which many RDF parsers support (if not, it’s simple to automatically convert it into other RDF serializations, like Turtle, RDF/XML, or JSON-LD). There are [many different tools and libraries](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3465/877) available for this purpose. (You should use an RDF-aware tool instead of trying to parse the file as HTML.)