# Get JSON-LD information from Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I would like to get a JSON-LD representation of Schema.org in the same way I can have an RDF version in http://topbraid.org/schema/.

I see the main page of Schema.org is represented with JSON-LD, but there are not type definitions as there are in the RDF version.

For a second question, how can a JSON-LD parser understand the properties of a Schema.org's Person type if it cannot access to such information in JSON-LD?

Comment: What do you mean with "the main page of Schema.org is represented with JSON-LD"?

Comment: @unor If you access http://schema.org (just the main page) with an `Accept` header with value `application/ld+json` you get a representation of properties (but not all) and vocabularies that schema.org uses, in JSON-LD.

Comment: Ah, yes. That should be the JSON-LD context (direct link to that file: [http://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json](http://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [canonical representation of Schema.org](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374829/1591669) is in HTML+RDFa.

RDFa is, like JSON-LD, a RDF serialization. It should be easy to convert from RDFa to JSON-LD with your favorite RDF tool, if needed.

Under https://schema.org/docs/tree.jsonld a JSON-LD file can be downloaded which seems to describe all types (but no properties). (Corresponding issue: [*Add a JSON(-LD) view of the entire type hierarchy*](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/318).)

Under http://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json the JSON-LD context file can be downloaded which seems to contain all types and properties. But it doesn’t state which included domain/range the properties have.

The issue [*Add more export formats (e.g. as offered but obsolete at schema.rdfs.org)*](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/208) tracks ideas/plans to provide other formats than RDFa.