# How to get class data also with attributes from schema.org

Tags: json, export, schema.org, json-ld

I am searching for a way, How can I get classes with attributes from schema.org. I found this JSON file https://schema.org/docs/tree.jsonld, but it doesnt have attributes. Is there a some complete data export from schema.org in JSON, or other javascript readable format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JSON-LD information from Schema.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236618/get-json-ld-information-from-schema-org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found an answer. Here is link to forum about this problem.
https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/945